# How can i setup GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS Environment variable in plesk server

Tags: reactjs, node.js, google-cloud-platform, next.js, plesk

I have a nextjs application which is hosted on plesk server, I have tried setting up `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` with absolute path `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/sub.domain.com/lib/google-creds.json`. But still it is giving me `Internal Server Error`

Here is my code:

```
// pages/api/text-to-speech.js
import textToSpeech from '@google-cloud/text-to-speech';
require('dotenv').config();

const client = new textToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();

export default async function handler(req, res) {

  const request = {
    input: { text:"Welcome to Stackoverflow" },
    voice: { languageCode: 'en-US', name: 'en-US-Wavenet-D', ssmlGender: 'NEUTRAL' },
    audioConfig: { audioEncoding: 'MP3' }
  };

  try {
    const response = await client.synthesizeSpeech(request);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/mp3');
    res.send(response?.[0].audioContent);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    res.status(400).json({ error: error });
  }
}
```

Comment: You are storing a secret in a subdirectory of your domain's path. That is dangerous. `Internal Server Error` can mean many things. Look in the logs and determine the exact cause.